# Ruby on Rails 3 Params Hash Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters

Let's say we are passing in something like :mash => true

Now inside of params I want to

takeit = params[:mash]

What class is takeit? It's not boolean of course.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a string.